# How do I inject data in my sidebar that is included in every single blade of my project

Tags: php, laravel, layout, routes, nested

I'm using a layout system and my sidebar is included in my master, and my master page is the layout for all my blades

```
//master.blade.php
<div clas="main-wrapper" id="app">
    @include('layout.sidebar')
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      @include('layout.header')
      <div class="page-content" >
        @yield('content')
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to display on the sidebar items the project names that belongs to the authenticated user.

So I tried the first solution which is to use the route function like this:

```
 //web.php
 Route::any('/home',function(){
  $p = DB::table('projets')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.ID_chercheur')
      ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
      ->where('projets.ID_chercheur','=',Auth::user()->id)
      ->get();
      return view('dashboard')->with(['projets' => $p]);    
  });
```

the problem with this solution that it works only in my dashboard view, any other view it won't work it will give me the following error:

```
ErrorException

    Undefined variable: projets (View: C:\laragon\www\Labo1\resources\views\layout\sidebar.blade.php)
```

I understand what the error means but I don't know how to fix it, I tried:

```
//web.php
Route::match(['get', 'post', 'PUT', 'PATCH','DELETE'], '/', function () {
  $p = DB::table('projets')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.ID_chercheur')
      ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
      ->where('projets.ID_chercheur','=',Auth::user()->id)
      ->get();
      return ['projets' => $p];
});
```

but it doesn't work either, could someone tell me what solution could I use?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 2):

Use **View Composer** to tackle the issue. **View composers** are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

**Implementation**

***Step 1 Create Service Provider***

`php artisan make:provider ViewServiceProvider`

***Step 2 Register Service Provider***

You will need to add the service provider to the `providers` array in the `config/app.php` configuration file.

Like add this `App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,` to `providers` array, then run `config:cache` to clear cache and regenerate config.

***Step 3 Write Logic in Provider's Boot Method***

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        

        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('layout.sidebar', function ($view) {
            $p = DB::table('projets')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.ID_chercheur')
            ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
            ->where('projets.ID_chercheur','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();

                $view->with('projets', $p);
        });
    }
}
```

then you can access `projets` in your blade like `{{projets}}` and the `foreach` over it or whatever.

[Further Refer to Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this in one of your ServiceProviders (e.g. AppServiceProvider)

```
View::composer('layout.sidebar', function ($view) {
$p = DB::table('projets')
  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.ID_chercheur')
  ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
  ->where('projets.ID_chercheur','=',Auth::user()->id)
  ->get();

                $view->with('projets', $p);
            });
```

I haven't tried it out myself. But I think it should also work for partials.

Comment: Idea is to share your data with the view layouts.sidebar

Answer (score 0):

**Another Approach**

if you have limited data to access in all views like for only `projects` data then definitely go for [`view composers`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) but if you think that in future you have to access multiple external data then you can make a separate `helper file` and write code there like make `functions` and then in your blade just simply call those functions.

***Implmentation***

Create a `helpers.php` file in your `app` folder and load it up with composer like:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php" // <---- ADD THIS
    ]
},
```

After adding that to your `composer.json` file, run the following command:

`composer dump-autoload`

If you don't like keeping your `helpers.php` file in your `app` directory (because it's not a PSR-4 namespaced class file), you can do what the `laravel.com` website does: store the `helpers.php` [in the `bootstrap` directory](https://github.com/laravel/laravel.com/blob/8d197f1c8f9a6968519e96778d8ed9976fb49590/bootstrap/helpers.php). Remember to set it in your `composer.json` file:

```
"files": [
    "bootstrap/helpers.php"
]
```

Then in your `helpers.php` file make a function

```
<?php

function getProjects()
{

  $p = \DB::table('projets')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.ID_chercheur')
            ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
            ->where('projets.ID_chercheur','=',Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();

   return $p;

}
```

and access it in blade like `{{ getProjects() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thank you so much for your answers but i found a simple way to resolve my problem
i wasn't familiar with the php syntax in laravel so my friend helped me and this solution seemed to help me:

```
@php
$projets=DB::table('projets')
       ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projets.chefProjet')
       ->select('projets.nom', 'users.name', 'users.prenom')
       ->where('projets.chefProjet','=',Auth::user()->id)
       ->get();
@endphp
```

...

I puted this piece of code in the top of my sidebar.blade.php and now i can work with the data in the same page and also the data is loaded with every other blade

```
 if(count($projets)>0)
          @foreach ($projets as $p)
          <li class="nav-item {{ active_class(['forms/*']) }}">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#forms" role="button" aria-expanded="{{ is_active_route(['forms/*']) }}" aria-controls="forms">
              <i class="link-icon" data-feather="trello"></i>
              <span class="link-title" name="monspan">{{$p->nom}} </span>
              <i class="link-arrow" data-feather="chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
     </li>
....
          @endforeach
     @elseif(count($projets)==0)
           <li class="nav-item">
              <p class="text-muted">Aucun projet active</p>
           </li>
     @endif
```

i got to learn about the providers from your answers so once again thank you for your time